# Appstore not automatically checking for updates since iOS 11

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore, ios

Just me or has the appstore app stopped automatic checks for app updates since iOS 11? Updates aren't found and hence the badge on the app icon isn't shown.
Only if I manually open the appstore app and refresh-pull the updates tab the app updates are polled.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has released the iOS 11.01 update, so I’d try downloading and installing that.

To install the update, go to Settings > General > Software Update.

Comment: 11.0.1 did nothing. In fact I still have to pull to refresh in updates in App Store to see any updates. Just opening App Store is not enough.